# Cannot use mutating member ... because append?

Tags: swift

I'm confused about why I am getting this error (swift 4.2.1).

```
// next, select only entries in range
let filteredDataOpt: [TimeSeriesEntry?] = filteredApps
    .map { data in
        let isInDate = dates.contains { date in
            guard let d = date else {
                return false
            }
            return Calendar.current.isDate(d, equalTo: data.date, toGranularity: Calendar.Component.day)
        }
        return isInDate ? timeSeriesDataFromAppData(data) : nil
    }.append(contentsOf: locationsData.map { data in
        let isInDate = dates.contains { date in
            guard let d = date else {
                return false
            }
            return Calendar.current.isDate(d, equalTo: data.date, toGranularity: Calendar.Component.day)
        }
        return isInDate ? timeSeriesDataFromLocationData(data) : nil
    })
```

This produces

> Cannot use mutating member on immutable value: function call returns immutable value

on the third line.

But this doesn't:

```
// next, select only entries in range
let filteredDataOpt: [AppData?] = filteredByApps
    .map { data in
        let isInDate = dates.contains { date in
            guard let d = date else {
                return false
            }
            return Calendar.current.isDate(d, equalTo: data.date, toGranularity: Calendar.Component.day)
        }
        return isInDate ? data : nil
}
let filteredData: [AppData] = filteredDataOpt.compactMap { $0 }
```

My confusion stems from the fact that I am manipulating a sequence with `append` rather than first assigning it to a constant and then `append`ing to it. Why is my sequence read-only?

**edit:** apparently map is always (And at first glance at least, bizarrely) returning a constant. In full, my solution is just:

```
var filteredDataOpt: [TimeSeriesEntry?] = filteredApps
    .map { data in
        let isInDate = dates.contains { date in
            guard let d = date else {
                return false
            }
            return Calendar.current.isDate(d, equalTo: data.date, toGranularity: Calendar.Component.day)
        }
        return isInDate ? self.timeSeriesData(appData: data) : nil
}
filteredDataOpt.append(contentsOf: self.locationsData.map { data in
    let isInDate = dates.contains { date in
        guard let d = date else {
            return false
        }
        return Calendar.current.isDate(d, equalTo: data.date, toGranularity: Calendar.Component.day)
    }
    return isInDate ? self.timeSeriesData(locationData: data) : nil
})
let filteredData = filteredDataOpt.compactMap { $0 }
```

But, does anyone else find that unsatisfactory? I'm stuck with:

- intermediate variables
- variables where what I need is just a constant

Comment: `apparently map is always (And at first glance at least, bizarrely) returning a constant` — mutability is not property of the value itself, but of it's "binding" (variable or constant); map returns just a "unbound" value.

Comment: Smaller example: `[1, 2].map({$0 * 2}).append(6)`

Comment: @user28434 This is actually very important. Even if you could use a mutating method on a temporary expression, the result would not be correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem can be reduced to the following:

```
let data = [1, 2, 3]
let data2 = [4, 5, 6]

let filteredData: [Int] = data
    .map { $0 }
    .append(contentsOf: data2.map { $0 })
```

The solution is to use concatenation instead of `append`:

```
let data = [1, 2, 3]
let data2 = [4, 5, 6]

let filteredData: [Int] = data
    .map { $0 }
    + data2.map { $0 }
```

For an explanation, this is similar to:

```
let a: Int = 0
let b = a += 1 // this is append
let c = (a + 1) += 1 // this is append with a temporary expression
```

(you would be adding into something that is immediately discarded and the value would not be stored into `c`).

which obviously should be done as

```
let a: Int = 0
let b = a + 1
```

Note that even if you could `append` on temporary return value, `append` does not have a return value and your result assigned to `filteredDataOpt` would be `Void`.

The reason why temporary expression are constant (immutable) is to prevent you from doing similar errors.

Comment: actually, I thought `appending` would do it.. but I am now getting `Value of type '[_]' has no member 'appending'`. The `+`method does work .. this is not just true of my data, but also your examples (with ``Value of type '[Int]' has no member 'appending'``). I believe `appending` can only ever work with strings. You might revise your answer.

Comment: @robertotomás you can easily declare an `appending(contentsOf:)` function yourself to mimic the behaviour of other standard library functions (such as `sort` vs `sorted`) like this: `extension Array {
    func appending<S: Sequence>(contentsOf newElements: S) -> Array where S.Element == Element {
        return self + Array(newElements)
    }
}`

Comment: @robertotomás You are right, I was sure there is `appending` but obviously it isn't there.

Answer (score 2):

Not an answer to your question but this will work

```
var filteredDataOpt: [TimeSeriesEntry?] = filteredApps
        .map { data in
            let isInDate = dates.contains { date in
                guard let d = date else {
                    return false
                }
                return Calendar.current.isDate(d, equalTo: data.date, toGranularity: Calendar.Component.day)
            }
            return isInDate ? timeSeriesDataFromAppData(data) : nil
        }
filteredDataOpt.append(contentsOf: locationsData.map { data in
            let isInDate = dates.contains { date in
                guard let d = date else {
                    return false
                }
                return Calendar.current.isDate(d, equalTo: data.date, toGranularity: Calendar.Component.day)
            }
            return isInDate ? timeSeriesDataFromLocationData(data) : nil})
```

Comment: I dont think the logic here is right .. if I declare it as `var filteredDataOpt` I get the same error.

Comment: @robertotomás You're right, my test code was wrong. This must mean map always returns an immutable array

Comment: hmm, that kinda defeats the typical mapreduce structure of functional languages. I imagine that there is no `mutableMap`?

Comment: @robertotomás, you can do it in two steps as in my update above

Answer (score 2):

The problem is method `append(contentsOf:)` is mutating and the returned element of any function in swift is by default immutable.

That's why you cannot call the method `append(contentsOf:)` on the array returned by `map` method.

Better you can use non mutating method `appending(contentsOf:)` for your code.

So your code will be:

```
// next, select only entries in range
let filteredDataOpt: [TimeSeriesEntry?] = filteredApps
    .map { data in
        let isInDate = dates.contains { date in
            guard let d = date else {
                return false
            }
            return Calendar.current.isDate(d, equalTo: data.date, toGranularity: Calendar.Component.day)
        }
        return isInDate ? timeSeriesDataFromAppData(data) : nil
    }.appending(contentsOf: locationsData.map { data in
        let isInDate = dates.contains { date in
            guard let d = date else {
                return false
            }
            return Calendar.current.isDate(d, equalTo: data.date, toGranularity: Calendar.Component.day)
        }
        return isInDate ? timeSeriesDataFromLocationData(data) : nil
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

Functions return immutable values. That's just the way it is in Swift. If you want it to be mutable, you have to store it in a `var` first.

However, you can use `+` to concatenate an `Array` with any `Sequence`. So if `filteredApps` is an `Array`, this should work:

```
    let filteredDataOpt: [TimeSeriesEntry?] = filteredApps
        .map { data in
            let isInDate = dates.contains { date in
                guard let d = date else {
                    return false
                }
                return Calendar.current.isDate(d, equalTo: data.date, toGranularity: Calendar.Component.day)
            }
            return isInDate ? self.timeSeriesData(appData: data) : nil
    } + self.locationsData.map { data in
        let isInDate = dates.contains { date in
            guard let d = date else {
                return false
            }
            return Calendar.current.isDate(d, equalTo: data.date, toGranularity: Calendar.Component.day)
        }
        return isInDate ? self.timeSeriesData(locationData: data) : nil
    }
    let filteredData = filteredDataOpt.compactMap { $0 }
```

There are several other things we can do to clean up this code also. We can factor out the date test:

```
    func isValid(_ candidate: Date) -> Bool {
        return dates.contains { date in
            guard let d = date else {
                return false
            }
            return Calendar.current.isDate(d, equalTo: candidate, toGranularity: Calendar.Component.day)
        }
    }

    let filteredDataOpt: [TimeSeriesEntry?] = filteredApps
        .map { data in
            return isValid(data.date) ? self.timeSeriesData(appData: data) : nil
    } + self.locationsData.map { data in
        return isValid(data.date) ? self.timeSeriesData(locationData: data) : nil
    }
    let filteredData = filteredDataOpt.compactMap { $0 }
```

Depending on your data, it might be better to pre-compute the valid `Date` ranges:

```
    let calendar = Calendar.current
    let dayRanges: [Range<Date>] = dates.lazy.compactMap({ $0 }).map({ date in
        let start = calendar.startOfDay(for: date)
        let end = calendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: start)!
        return start ..< end
    })

    func isValid(_ candidate: Date) -> Bool {
        return dayRanges.contains(where: { $0.contains(candidate) })
    }
```

We could also split the filtering from the transforming. That lets us eliminate the use of `compactMap`:

```
    let filteredData = Array(filteredApps.lazy.filter({ isValid($0.date) }).map(self.timeSeriesData))
        + locationsData.lazy.filter({ isValid($0.date) }).map(self.timeSeriesData)
```

Or we could use `compactMap` twice:

```
    let filteredData = filteredApps.compactMap({ isValid($0.date) ? self.timeSeriesData(appData: $0) : nil })
        + locationsData.compactMap({ isValid($0.date) ? self.timeSeriesData(locationData: $0) : nil })
```