# Calendar.current.isDate equalTo toGranularity: Calendar.Component.Day has strange matching behavior

Tags: swift

the below code was originally without the "Z" in the `matchingDate` field, and printed results like:

```
true comparing 2017-08-28 13:06:54 +0000 to matching 2017-08-28 05:00:00 +0000
false comparing 2017-08-28 04:22:42 +0000 to matching 2017-08-28 05:00:00 +0000
false comparing 2017-08-28 00:00:01 +0000 to matching 2017-08-28 05:00:00 +0000
true comparing 2017-08-28 20:24:00 +0000 to matching 2017-08-28 05:00:00 +0000
```

So I thought my problem was UTC. But, when it is corrected (as below), it prints:

```
false comparing 2017-08-28 13:06:54 +0000 to matching 2017-08-28 00:00:00 +0000
true comparing 2017-08-28 04:22:42 +0000 to matching 2017-08-28 00:00:00 +0000
true comparing 2017-08-28 00:00:01 +0000 to matching 2017-08-28 00:00:00 +0000
false comparing 2017-08-28 20:24:00 +0000 to matching 2017-08-28 00:00:00 +0000
```

This is unexpected (all 4 should match). What is wrong?

```
import Foundation

extension Array {
    // src: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54217704/cannot-use-mutating-member-because-append#comment-95266763
    func appending<S: Sequence>(contentsOf newElements: S) -> Array where S.Element == Element {
        return self + Array(newElements)
    }
} 

let dfCandidate = DateFormatter()
dfCandidate.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssZ"

let dfMatching = DateFormatter()
dfMatching.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-ddZ"
guard let matchingDate = dfMatching.date(from: "2017-08-28Z") else {
    preconditionFailure()
}

let dates1 = [
    "2017-08-28 13:06:54",
    "2017-08-28 04:22:42"
]
let dates2 = [
    "2017-08-28 00:00:01",
    "2017-08-28 20:24:00"
]

let matchingDates: [Date] = dates1
.map { candidateDate in
      guard let date = dfCandidate.date(from: candidateDate + "Z") else {
          return nil
      }

      let isInDate = Calendar.current.isDate(date, equalTo: matchingDate, toGranularity: Calendar.Component.day)

      print("\(isInDate) comparing \(String(describing: date)) to matching \(String(describing: matchingDate))")

      return isInDate ? date : nil
     }
.appending(contentsOf: dates2.map { candidateDate in
                                   guard let date = dfCandidate.date(from: candidateDate + "Z") else {
                                       return nil
                                   }

                                   let isInDate = Calendar.current.isDate(date, equalTo: matchingDate, toGranularity: Calendar.Component.day)

                                   print("\(isInDate) comparing \(String(describing: date)) to matching \(String(describing: matchingDate))")

                                   return isInDate ? date : nil
                                  })
.compactMap { $0 }

print(matchingDates)
```

(note: swift 4.2.1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are mixing timezones.

Your use of `Z` in the date formats and the date strings that you parse means that those date strings are treated as being in the UTC timezone. That may or may not be what you want.

Your use of `Calendar.current.isDate` means that the two dates are compared using your own current timezone, not the UTC timezone. So depending on where you live and how far the givens dates are from midnight, the two dates may be on the same day in one timezone but two different days in the other timezone.

Your code may be perfectly correct as is once you understand that the "strange" results are in fact correct based on the given timezones.

You need to determine which timezone the date/time strings represent. Then you need to determine which timezone you wish to compare them in.

Example (for someone living in the eastern US where it is currently UTC-5)

You parse the string `2017-08-28 13:06:54Z`. That is the time in the UTC timezone. You can see that in your output of `2017-08-28 13:06:54 +0000`.

You also parse `2017-08-28Z`. This is treated as midnight UTC time. Printing this `Date` would show `2017-08-28 00:00:00 +0000`.

In UTC time those two dates are on the same day.

However, when you use `Calendar.current` it looks at dates in your own local time (UTC-5 in this example).

This means the first date in local time is `2017-08-28 08:06:54 -0500` and the second date in local time is `2017-08-27 19:00:00 -0500`.

In local time, those two dates are not on the same day.

Solution:

If you want all dates to be treated as UTC dates and you want to compare each set of dates in the UTC timezone, then you should update your code to something like the following:

```
let utc = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)!

let dfCandidate = DateFormatter()
dfCandidate.timeZone = utc
dfCandidate.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"

let dfMatching = DateFormatter()
dfMatching.timeZone = utc
dfMatching.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
guard let matchingDate = dfMatching.date(from: "2017-08-28") else {
    preconditionFailure()
}

let dates1 = [
    "2017-08-28 13:06:54",
    "2017-08-28 04:22:42"
]
let dates2 = [
    "2017-08-28 00:00:01",
    "2017-08-28 20:24:00"
]

var utcCalendar = Calendar.current
utcCalendar.timeZone = utc

let matchingDates: [Date] = dates1
    .map { candidateDate in
        guard let date = dfCandidate.date(from: candidateDate) else {
            return nil
        }

        let isInDate = utcCalendar.isDate(date, equalTo: matchingDate, toGranularity: Calendar.Component.day)

        print("\(isInDate) comparing \(String(describing: date)) to matching \(String(describing: matchingDate))")

        return isInDate ? date : nil
    }
    .appending(contentsOf: dates2.map { candidateDate in
        guard let date = dfCandidate.date(from: candidateDate + "Z") else {
            return nil
        }

        let isInDate = utcCalendar.isDate(date, equalTo: matchingDate, toGranularity: Calendar.Component.day)

        print("\(isInDate) comparing \(String(describing: date)) to matching \(String(describing: matchingDate))")

        return isInDate ? date : nil
    })
    .compactMap { $0 }

print(matchingDates)
```

This creates a UTC timezone and uses it with both date formatters and it creates a Calendar set in the UTC timezone for doing the date comparisons.

Comment: no, Im not mixing timezones. "Z" in one Date is the same as Z in another, as can be seen in the print statements (both evaluate to +0000)
edit: oooh. Current is the problem :) my bad

Comment: Is there a `Calendar.utc.isDate` or something?

Comment: @robertotomás See my updated answer showing a clear example of what I mean by mixing timezones and why you get the results that you see.

Comment: yes I got it even before you added that, but thanks for the added clarity (note, both date values are actually in the print out, you dont have to posit what printing the second date would show, I showed it originally -- I felt this illustrated the source of the confusion). Is there a `Calendar.utc.isDate` or something so I can compare the two dates in the raw?

Comment: @robertotomás See my newest update with a full solution.